# Google app engine: fetching a lot of urls and data processing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

In my app I fetch a large number of urls and parse information.
I am trying to use deferred library and task queues.
I split fetching of every single page into separate task with following processing.
Below is an example of deferred task:

```
def deftask(somevalue, pagenumber):
    fetch url
    parse with beautiful soup
    some processing
    saving to datastore
```

After that in post handler I run this tasks in loop:

```
for i in range(0, 200):
     deferred.defer(deftask, somevalue, i)
```

So just for 200 iterations it takes about 5-8 mins. That is a very long.

Same performance with task queues. I send task in loop too:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/taskhandler', params = {'page' : i}, transactional=True)
```

There is just one queue.

So my question is how I can improve performance?

Should I change something in my approach? Or may be goggle app engine is inappropriate for this aim? And I should move my project to VPS hosting with django or etc.?

Comment: 5 mins to add 200 tasks sound like really long, but consider to use task to add tasks ;)

Comment: @DmitrySadovnychyi not to add, to execute,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control execution time in queue.yaml, by setting rate to 10/s for example. Be sure that your module configuration is set to auto scaling, or use proper manual scaling.

```
queue:
- name: default
  rate: 5/s
```

Also take a look into your logs and look for failing tasks, which could be a reason why they need so much time to complete.

Use separated tasks for each:

```
fetch url
parse with beautiful soup
some processing
saving to datastore
```

So if `parse with beautiful soup` fail it will not fetch this url again, but will get this content from the datastore.